# LINQ for SQL statement that returns single scalar value

Tags: linq-to-sql, scalar

I want to execute the following select:

```
SELECT 0 as Value
```

What is the correlating syntax in LINQ for SQL?

**Edit**

I want to use the correlating LINQ for SQL statement in a Concat() call like this

```
var c = (from a in mytable select a.Value).Concat(select 0).Sum();
```

As you can see, Concat(select 0) obviously doesn't compile. Any ideas?

**Edit 2**

David suggested to use a simple collection instead. I've tried

```
private decimal[] mZeroDecimals = new[] { 0.0m };
...

public void MyFunction()
{
  var c = (from a in mytable select a.Value).Concat(mZeroDecimals).Sum();
  ...
```

but it throws an exception **Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator**.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually querying anything, so there is no LINQ involved.  You're just creating an anonymous object with a single property called `Value`:

```
var obj = new { Value = 0 };
```

---

**Edit:** Based on your comment, it sounds like you want this object in a collection.  That doesn't make it a LINQ query (since you're still not *querying* anything), but you can declare a collection just as easily as a single object.  Something like this:

```
var coll = new[] { new { Value = 0 } };
```

Since this is a collection, it can be used with any of the enumerable extension methods that LINQ uses, which sounds like what you're trying to do.

Comment: I really need the LINQ for SQL statement as i want to use it in a .Concat() call. I've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: In that case you just want a collection rather than a single object.  I've updated the answer to show how to create that.

Comment: Yes, using a collection compiles but throws an exception **Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator**.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: Perhaps you can more clearly describe what it is you're trying to accomplish here?  There may be a much simpler solution.

Comment: Please have a look at the original question. I want to create a sum of multiple rows but that only works when there are actual rows. The idea here is to add a union select to ensure that at least one row is returned and Sum() doesn't crash.